# Help with languages for specific tasks

Tags: programming-languages

What language I should start study for these tasks:

- working with p2p
- web service
- working with webcams
- video capture
- video streaming(web etc.)
- same with audio(recording,streaming)

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would say C# and python

i saw most of this work done in C# cause the ,net framework is very huge & has a good support , even for 3rd party libraries

python is a cool language and you'll find many libraries that will help you in your work

Answer (score 0):

c# would do nicely. Asp.net on the server and silverlight on the client. One language many benefits.